# Calculate Data Usage, Voice usage in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi I am developing iPhone application in which i want to

1. Calculate Data usage for given time period
2. Calculate Voice usage for given time period
3. Determine whether Roaming is on or off on the device

My question is, Is it possible on iOS to do these operations?

If yes, what could be the possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

No. On a normal, factory setup iPhone (i.e. no jailbreaking) information about the total amount of data and voice usage is unavailable to applications.